# An H2 estimate for Helmholtz equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde, laplacian, regularity

How to show the following statement?

> Let $\Omega$ be a bounded <strike>**Lipschitz**</strike> **convex** domain. If $u$ satisfies the following equation,
>
> $$
>  -\Delta u - k^2 u = f \quad\mbox{ in }\Omega \\ \nabla u \cdot n + i k u = g \quad\mbox{ on }\partial \Omega $$
>
> Then the following estimate holds:
>
> $$ |u|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq C \left(\Vert f+k^2 u \Vert_{0,\Omega} +
>  \Vert\nabla u \cdot n\Vert_{\frac{1}{2},\partial \Omega}\right). $$

Thank you for any hint on this.

**Remark:**

1. This statement is quoted from a thesis [On generalized finite element methods by Jens Markus Melenk](http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~melenk/publications/diss.ps.gz) on P.121. It says using regularity theory for '$-\Delta$' to get the statement.
2. I made a mistake. The requirement for $\Omega$ should be bounded convex, not bounded Lipschitz.

Comment: Why do you know that the given assertion is true?

Comment: The statement was stated in a thesis, afterwards it was quoted in another paper. And that paper is cited many times.

Comment: Then I suggest you to include the appropriate references in your question, to give it some context.

Comment: Is $H^2$ here the $L^2$ Sobolev space with 2 derivatives? What are the norms $0,\Omega$ and $\frac12,\Omega$?

Comment: @StefanKohl Thank you for your advice. I have added a link to the thesis.

Comment: This boils down to showing that the Dirichlet to Neumann operator does not have imaginary eigenvalues, which follows easily from a standard energy estimate. This is not a research level question.

Comment: Yes. $0,\Omega$ norm is the L2 norm in $\Omega$ and $1/2,\Omega$ norm is the norm for the Sobolev space $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Do you have any introductory reference to this? Thank you.